# How to list all the files of a specific extension in a folder in VS Code?

Tags: search, visual-studio-code, directory, editor, file-extension

How to list all the files of a specific extension in a folder in VS Code?

Let us suppose I have a folder with a deep subfolders structure. In that structure there are a lot of files of different extensions like: .html, .ts, .scss. Now I want to get a list of all the files with the .html extension. How can I do that?

Preferably I want not to see the subfolders structure. Just as when I search for a specific word I can limit file types to a specific extension in a specific folder - in this case I am given a list of files, with which I can easily work without a need to expand directories or read through the different from what I need extensions.

Partial solution for the problem is to figure out what patterns one is looking for in the files, then it is possible to use the in files search. E.g. `./pathToMyFolder/**/*.html`. But I just need to open each .html file and I do not have a pattern to look for. And expanding each subdirectory and traversing it makes things really messy and cumbersome for me. Also, there are files with other extensions and filtering them out also takes time.

Comment: Are you using the filter on type option in the file explorer?  Just type `.html` when the explorer is focused, then hover over the little flyout of the letters you typed and make sure the `filter on type` is enabled.

Comment: @Mark, very cool. That is helpful. If only it would be possible to get rid from the folders structure and scope in to a specific folder it would be awesome. But your comment solves my problem partially. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Open the file picker - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Type `*.<desired extension>` (i.e `*.cs`)

Comment: Searching for `*.js` gives both `.json` and `.js`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what the OP meant, but for me this isn't very helpful because I want to work my way through the list looking at each one, but the order can change when I open it multiple times, and it requires me to open it over and over instead of just clicking the next file.